# How to identify the coefficients in a series expansion on a non-orthogonal basis?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, orthogonality

The solution of a PDE lead to a series expansion of the form
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( A_n \cos \left( \lambda_n z\right) + B_n \sin \left( \lambda_n z \right) \right) = f(z) \, , 
$$
where $z \in [0,L]$ and $f(z)$ is a known function.
If $\lambda_n = n\pi/L$ then the coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$ can easily be determined (Fourier coefficients).
In my case, $\lambda_n$ are known eigenvalues that are determined numerically.

> Note that for $n \ne m$, $\lambda_n \ne \lambda_m + 2k\pi$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ holds.

I was wondering whether there is a way to identify $A_n$ and $B_n$ when the basis functions are not orthogonal. Thank you.

**Example:**

Consider 3 terms in the series with $f(z) = \delta(z)$, $\lambda_0 = 1$, $\lambda_1 = 2$, and $\lambda_2 = 4$.

Comment: for all $\lambda_n \ne \lambda_m$ we have $cos(\lambda_nz) \ne cos(\lambda_m z)$ and $sin(\lambda_nz) \ne \sin(\lambda_m z)$ right?

Comment: @crush3dice Yes. i will mention that in the question

Comment: Are the $\lambda_n$ 'related' to $L$ in any way?

Comment: @copper.hat in general yes. Just take $L=1$ for instance.

Comment: maybe you could apply some rotation to the basis $((\cos\lambda_nz)_n,(\sin\lambda_nz)_n)$ so that it gets orthogonal. You could approximate that by ignoring those basis functions that have low magnitute for the vector you want to calc $A_n, B_n$ for. Then one could use Gram Schmidt

Comment: Okay but then you would need the magnitudes before you have them already :D. But maybe that idea helps

Comment: @crush3dice Perhaps a detailed answer will help understand your point.

Comment: If $f$ an $L$-periodic function?

Comment: I have no clue how to make that numerical. I am not into numerics. But since we have a  hilbertspace here with countable infinite basis we could make the basis orthogonal in infinite steps. Then we could find out the operator that performs this operation and apply that one to our functions before we calculate the coefficients. Then we are in the orthogonal case which is more familiar and since our operator should be bijective too we can inverse it afterwards and get the coefficients you wanted.

Comment: @copper.hat in this problem, $f$ is a Dirac function, generally $f(z) = \delta (z-z_0)$ with $z_0 \in (0,L)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this came from a self-adjoint PDE, and if you have endpoint conditions of the form
$$
                Af(a)+Bf'(a)=0,\;\;\; Cf(b)+Df'(b)=0,
$$
then you can end up with trigonometric expansions where the periods are non-harmonic. But that does not mean they are not orthogonal, in which case the ODE solutions will still be orthogonal, and you will still Fourier expansions in orthogonal functions.

For example, this is a a self-adjoint ODE with orthogonal eigenfunctions that can be used to expand anything in $L^2[a,b]$:
$$
                       -f''+\lambda f = 0 \\
                   \cos(\alpha)f(a)+\sin(\alpha)f'(a)=0\\
                   \cos(\beta)f(b)+\sin(\beta)f'(b)=0.
$$
The general case for the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ is that they are not evenly spaced. However, the eigenfunctions will be mutually orthogonal with respect to the inner product on $L^2[a,b]$, and they will form a complete orthogonal basis of $L[a,b]$. For infinite intervals, you may have a mixed discrete and continuous Fourier expansion.